# JavaScript equivalent to php's __call

Tags: javascript

I don't think there's such thing because I guess I would have found it by now but the only way to be certain is to be given a straight answer, therefore I must ask before I give up. I need a method that's going to be called every time I try to access an object's method. Is there such a thing in JavaScript?

Basically I need to run a couple of lines before and after **each** of my object's methods. Hardcoding them is really not an option. The other thing I thought of was to have a main method like

```
Mainmethod(ActualMethod, Parameters)
```

But this really doesn't look good to me, I'd really like not having to do this.

Comment: Exists, but non-standard (FF only), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod

Comment: @elclanrs Yeah I found this too, so sad it's browser specific..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for a particular object or a particular type of object, you can dynamically replace all the methods with your own stub that does your pre-work, calls the original method and then does your post-work.

Something like this will work:

```
function overideMethods(obj) {
    // can pass either an instantiated object (hooks existing methods on the object)
    //    or a function constructor (hooks methods in the prototype)
    if (typeof obj === "function") {
        obj = obj.prototype;
    }
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "function") {
            (function(origMethod) {
                obj[prop] = function() {
                    var retVal, args;

                    // do your pre-work here

                    // make copy of args passed to this method
                    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

                    // call original method with proper args
                    retVal = origMethod.apply(this, args);

                    // do your post-work here

                    return retVal;
                };
            })(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7LzQj/

---

You can now pass this function either an object or a constructor function.  If you pass it an object, it will hook the existing enumerable methods on that object.  If you pass it a constructor function, it will hook the methods on the constructor's prototype.  This allows you to set up the hooks for all objects made from an entire constructor (in advance) or just hook an individual object.

---

If your object adds methods dynamically, either in the constructor or later in the life of the object and you want those methods hooked, then you will need to call `overideMethods()` on the object AFTER those methods are added - you will not be able to just call it on the constructor.

Comment: That sounds like the thing that I'm looking for, could you give me a simple example because I'm having a hard time with javascript's object model..

Comment: You can create a `method` method that calls your methods, like `instance.method('mymethod')`

Comment: @php_nub_qq - I added a function that replaces all methods with an override stub.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: If you think in a functional manner, you could implement a couple decorators, `after` and `before`, compose them, then when you add the method you decorate it like `foo: decor(function(){...})`

Comment: This won't work if method not exists. why not just using `Object.protoype.call = function(method){/* Do the magics here */; var _ret = this[method].apply(this,[].prototype.slice.call(arguments));/* Another magic part */; return _ret;}` and check method not exists any where you like!!

Comment: I don't really need to cover non-existent methods, it's just how it's done in PHP and probably what gets me confused

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you tell me what's the purpose of this `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)`, because it seems that if I replace it with just `arguments` it works as well?

Comment: @php_nub_qq - I wasn't sure if just plain `arguments` would work in all versions of all browsers.  The `.apply()` method specifies that the second parameter should be an array.  The `arguments` object is "array-like", but isn't an actual array and does not have all the array methods.  So I was being cautious and I copied the elements from the `arguments` object into an actual array and used that.  `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);` is a well known way to copy the arguments object into an actual array.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - Implemented an enhanced version that can be passed either an instantiated object (so it will hook the methods currently on that object) or it can be passed a constructor function (it will hook all methods on the prototype) so all future objects created from the constructor will be hooked.  It can be used either way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution with function decorators. If you have something like Underscore at hand you can trim the code a bit, but I'm assuming you don't.

A decorator is a higher-order function that returns a modified version of another function. Decorators are a safer approach to monkey patching in some situations but it all depends on your needs.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/ApaLAVab/1/edit

```
function compose(f, g) {
  return function() {
    return f(g.apply(this, arguments));
  };
}

function before(fn) {
  return function() {
    console.log('before'); // code before method
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

function after(fn) {
  return function() {
    fn.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('after'); // code after method
  };
}

var run = compose(before, after);

function A() {}

A.prototype = {
  say: run(function(name) { // decorate method
    console.log('Hello '+ name);
  })
};

var a = new A();
a.say('Peter');
//^ before
//  Hello Peter
//  after
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add it to the constructor, so you don't have to run it manually:

```
function SimpleClass(){   
    this.overideMethods();
}

SimpleClass.prototype.overideMethods = function() {
    var obj = this;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "function") {
            console.log(prop);
            (function(origMethod) {
                obj[prop] = function() {
                    var retVal, args;
                    // do your pre-work here
                    alert("before function call");

                    // make copy of args passed to this method
                    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

                    // call original method with proper args
                    retVal = origMethod.apply(this, args);

                    // do your post-work here
                    alert("after function call");

                    return retVal;
                };
            })(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}

SimpleClass.prototype.testFn = function(){
    alert("In the function.");
};

var testObj = new SimpleClass();
testObj.testFn();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awesomepeter/wvxAd/1/
Credit to jfriend00 though, i wanted to do the same thing as him just came a little bit too late ;) So i just copypasted his answer and improved.